# How to count number of lines in a file in a Makefile?

Tags: bash, makefile

I have a Makefile in which I have a text file and a certain number. I would like to compare the number of lines in that text file to see if it is equal to or greater than that number, but haven't had success using the wc bash command.

I've tried using wc on the text file, but $(wc -l < filename.txt) always evaluates as empty, making ifeq($(wc -l < filename.txt), number)) error out. I've tried using the bash syntax for if statements, but that didn't work either.

e.g.

```
    TEST="$(wc -l < missing_test_line_count.txt)"
    TEST1=$(wc -l missing_test_line_count.txt)
    TEST2=`wc -l missing_test_line_count.txt`
    TEST3="$(wc -l missing_test_line_count.txt)"
```

Doing @echo $(value TEST) for any of these variables (TEST thru TEST3) results in an empty output.

I've also tried to put the number of lines in the text file into another text file (e.g. linecount.txt with a single line that says '30'). Then I tried to get that file content stored into a variable so I could compare it to the number, but that hasn't worked because I cannot define the variable at the beginning.

Any suggestions? Is this possible, or do I have to write a script separately? Would like to do it within the Makefile if possible.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should specify, that you need GNU make's syntax (your reference to `ifeq` is one's only clue to that).

Back to your actual question, there is no `wc` function in gmake itself. What you're trying to do is to execute an external command. You do that with a `shell` function:

```make
TEST=    $(shell wc -l < missing_test_line_count.txt)
```

In BSD make's the same is achieved with the `!=`-assignment:

```make
TEST!=   wc -l < missing_test_line_count.txt
```

Comment: Note newer versions of GNU make (4.2 and up) support `!=` as well.

Answer (score 0):

To run a shell as part of a variable expansion in a GNUMakefile, you need to use the `shell` function:

```
TEST:=$(shell wc -l < missing_test_line_count.txt)
```

will run the command in question when this line is read in the Makefile, setting `TEST` to be the result.  Alternately you can use

```
TEST=$(shell wc -l < missing_test_line_count.txt)
```

which will run the command each time the `$(TEST)` variable is expanded.

Note that this function (and functions in general) is a GNUMake extension.  Normal make does not support doing this.